# Replace text strings in a file that start with certain characters

Tags: python, variables, replace

I would like to replace text in a file by searching for specific letters at the beginning of the string.  For example here is a section of the file:

```
 6  HT     4.092000    4.750000   -0.502000     0     5     7
 7  HT     5.367000    5.548000   -0.325000     0     5     6
 8  OT    -5.470000    5.461000    1.463000     0     9    10
 9  HT    -5.167000    4.571000    1.284000     0     8    10
10  HT    -4.726000    6.018000    1.235000     0     8     9
11  OT    -4.865000   -5.029000   -3.915000     0    12    13
12  HT    -4.758000   -4.129000   -3.608000     0    11    13
```

I would like to use "HT" as the search and be able to replace the "space0space" with 2002.  When I try I replace all 0 with 2002 and not the column that is just 0.  After this I need to then search "OT" and replace the 0 column with 2001.

So basically I need to search a string that identify the line and replace a column specific string while the text that lies between is variable.  The output needs to be printed to a new_file.xyz.  Also I will be doing this repeatedly on lots of files so it would be great to be a script that can typed in front of the file that will be operated on.  Thanks.

Comment: Please provide what you already tried to do

Comment: Sorry this did not keep the file format.

Comment: Here is what I did but I can't specify the search part to find the HT..#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$^I = '.bak'; # create a backup copy 

while (<>) {
   s/ 0 /2002/g; # do the replacement
   print; # print to the modified file
}

Comment: I got the python replace script from an earlier post.

Comment: The file form should be line 1) "6 HT 4.092000 4.750000 -0.502000 0 5 7" line 2) "7 HT 5.367000 5.548000 -0.325000 0 5 6" line 3) "8 OT -5.470000 5.461000 1.463000 0 9 10" etc this all lines up in columns in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you (for HT):

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

new_lines = []

for line in lines:
    if "HT" in line:
        new_line = line.replace(' 0 ', '2002')
        new_lines.append(new_line)
    else:
        new_lines.append(line)


content = ''.join(new_lines)
print(content)


#  6  HT     4.092000    4.750000   -0.502000    2002    5     7
#  7  HT     5.367000    5.548000   -0.325000    2002    5     6
#  8  OT    -5.470000    5.461000    1.463000     0     9    10
#  9  HT    -5.167000    4.571000    1.284000    2002    8    10
# 10  HT    -4.726000    6.018000    1.235000    2002    8     9
# 11  OT    -4.865000   -5.029000   -3.915000     0    12    13
# 12  HT    -4.758000   -4.129000   -3.608000    2002   11    13
```

Repeat the same logic (add to the case or otherwise) for other line identifiers.

If you put this in a function, you could use it to replace all by id:

```
def _find_and_replace(current_lines, line_id, value):
    lines = []
    for l in current_lines:
        lines.append(l.replace(' 0 ', value)) if line_id in l else lines.append(l)
    return ''.join(lines)


with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    new_lines = _find_and_replace(lines, line_id='HT', value='2002')
    print(new_lines)
```

Though, if you have many identifiers, I would implement a solution which won't go through the list of lines every time but rather lookup the identifier as it iterates the lines.

Comment: When I tried this I got errors.  I tried to make the script rep_0_2002.py as #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$^I = '.bak'; # create a backup copy 

with open(<>) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

new_lines = []

for line in lines:
    if "HT" in line:
        new_line = line.replace(' 0 ', '2002')
        new_lines.append(new_line)
    else:
        new_lines.append(line)
          
         
content = ''.join(new_lines)
print(content)

Comment: I did get this to work, but it just prints on the screen, and I need it to print to a new file.  How do I get it to print to a new file?

Answer (score 0):

The solution using [***fileinput***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fileinput.html?highlight=fileinput#fileinput) module, `re.search()` and `re.sub()` functions:

```
import fileinput, re

with fileinput.input(files=("lines.txt"), inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        if (re.search(r'\bHT\b', line)):  # checks if line contains `HT` column
            print(re.sub(r' 0 ', '2002', line).strip())
        elif (re.search(r'\OT\b', line)): # checks if line contains `OT` column
            print(re.sub(r' 0 ', '2001', line).strip())
        else:
            print(line)
```

The file contents after processing:

```
6  HT     4.092000    4.750000   -0.502000    2002    5     7
7  HT     5.367000    5.548000   -0.325000    2002    5     6
8  OT    -5.470000    5.461000    1.463000    2001    9    10
9  HT    -5.167000    4.571000    1.284000    2002    8    10
10  HT    -4.726000    6.018000    1.235000    2002    8     9
11  OT    -4.865000   -5.029000   -3.915000    2001   12    13
12  HT    -4.758000   -4.129000   -3.608000    2002   11    13
```

---

> **Optional in-place filtering**: if the keyword argument `inplace=True` is passed to `fileinput.input()` or to the `FileInput`
>   constructor, the file is moved to a backup file and standard output is
>   directed to the input file (if a file of the same name as the backup
>   file already exists, it will be replaced silently). This makes it
>   possible to write a filter that rewrites its input file in place.

Comment: Hello RomanPerekhrest. When I tried this I get errors: Bareword found where operator expected at /home/adutton/python_scripts/rep_0_20012.py line 10, near ") as"
 (Missing operator before as?)
Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at /home/adutton/python_scripts/rep_0_20012.py line 10, near "),"
syntax error at /home/adutton/python_scripts/rep_0_20012.py line 10, near ") as f"
Bad name after r' at /home/adutton/python_scripts/rep_0_20012.py line 12.

Comment: Here is the script that I tried to make: #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$^I = '.bak'; # create a backup copy 

import fileinput, re

with fileinput.input(files=("lines.txt"), inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        if (re.search(r'\bHT\b', line)):  # checks if line contains `HT` column
            print(re.sub(r' 0 ', '2002', line).strip())
        elif (re.search(r'\OT\b', line)): # checks if line contains `OT` column
            print(re.sub(r' 0 ', '2001', line).strip())
        else:
            print(line)

Comment: @Drewucla, I think you've made some errors in your code. It should work fine. What is Python version?

Comment: Python version is Python 2.7.5.   Also I figured out that I had combined the beginning of a perl script.  When I replace that to make a file "rep_0_20012.py" as #!/usr/bin/python
import fileinput, re
with fileinput.input(files=("lines.txt"), inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        if (re.search(r'\bHT\b', line)):  # checks if line contains `HT` column
            print(re.sub(r' 0 ', '2002', line).strip())
        elif (re.search(r'\OT\b', line)): # checks if line contains `OT` column
            print(re.sub(r' 0 ', '2001', line).strip())
        else:
            print(line)

Comment: I tried to use this file as $ rep_0_20012.py test_replace.xyz and I get these errors Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adutton/python_scripts/rep_0_20012.py", line 5, in <module>
    with fileinput.input(files=("lines.txt"), inplace=True) as f:
AttributeError: FileInput instance has no attribute '__exit__'

Comment: python 2.7 requires another older syntax and another module implementation. You have two ways: to change syntax and `fileinput` module implementation OR to upgrade your old Python. You are loosing a lot of good features and improvements while staying at old Python

Comment: This is a school cluster so I'm not sure about upgrading, I can check.  Can you suggest how I solve this using older syntax?